# Why is my case statement returning a NULL value when I don't think it should?

Tags: mysql, case-statement

Question is at the bottom but in short, the table I'm creating is giving my Null values for the field Division even when the links match my case expression and I cant seem to find why.

I am creating a table to assign divisions according to a link url within the program:

```
create table set_divisions as
  select distinct campaign, offer,
   case
   when upper(link) like '%NORTH%' then 'NORTH'
   when upper(link) like '%SOUTH%' then 'SOUTH'
   when upper(link) like '%EAST%'  then 'EAST'
   when upper(link) like '%WEST%'  then 'WEST'
   ELSE NULL
   END AS DIVISION
   FROM TABLE A;
```

I then get a lot of NULL's in Division so I'm trying to see what links I'm missing as they all should have a value in Division. Each campaign does have multiple links some not associated with north, south, east or west but every campaign should also contain one of these links from the case statement.

I then run the following:

```
select distinct link
from  A, set_divisions S
where A.campaigncode = S.campaigncode
and   A.offercode    = S.offercode
and (
     upper(link) like '%NORTH%'
     or upper(link) like '%SOUTH%'
     or upper(link) like '%EAST%'
     or upper(link) like '%WEST%');
```

The results come back with links that have `NORTH`, `SOUTH`, `EAST` AND `WEST` in them.

So my question is what am I doing wrong in my case expression when creating my table, that is causing it to miss these links?

examples of links being missed are(I only used south and east but there are similar links for all four):

```
http://product.south.com/information/preference
http://sports.east.com/unsubscribe/?email=%%Linkurl9%%
```

Thanks and this is my first post so I apologize ahead of time if I missed something or my code looks crappy lol.

Reighlo

Comment: For the sake of testing, try running `SELECT link FROM A WHERE UPPER(link) NOT LIKE '%NORTH%' AND UPPER(link) NOT LIKE '%SOUTH%' AND UPPER(link) NOT LIKE '%EAST%' AND UPPER(link) NOT LIKE '%WEST%';`

Comment: Keep in mind if there are links that will not match any of those, they will be processed in the first query too, there is nothing special about DISTINCT that will remove them from the results.

Comment: I ran the query including campaign and offer and got a list of campaign/offers back. I then ran that where the conditions you suggested do exist and the results showed they do exists. With further investigation I found that there were multiple Campaign/offer combinations sent out with the exact same campaign/offer. One without the link I'm searching for and another with that link. The emails we send out have anywhere from 5 to 10 links in them. So the query exactly as you suggested brings back thousands of links as my data set goes back to 2012.

Comment: That indicates you have plenty of rows with data that will result in the CASE statement yielding null. You must filter them out with where conditions as stated in the first paragraph of first answer. DISTINCT will only eliminate duplicate/identical result rows; it will not eliminate rows with NULL value for DIVISION when there are result rows with non-null values, only when there are multiple NULLs, and even then not the "first".

Comment: Thanks for the help and I was able to find a solution last night, sorry I just saw your response now. So I did find 3000 combinations of campaign/offers that were sent multiple times. Sometimes with the links I'm looking for and other times without them. This may have been the long way but I created two tables which I'm thinking I can create as one with multiple inline views. After doing this I found divisions for all combinations except 12, which truly did not have the keywords I was looking for. I will post my solution later today.

Answer (score 0):

In the second query, your `WHERE` clause specifies that link must contain NORTH, SOUTH, EAST, or WEST. Your first query does not contain a similar `WHERE` clause.

You can run this to find links not containing NORTH, SOUTH, EAST or WEST to troubleshoot:

```
select distinct link
from  A, set_divisions S
where A.campaigncode = S.campaigncode
and   A.offercode    = S.offercode
and upper(link) not like '%NORTH%'
and upper(link) not like '%SOUTH%'
and upper(link) not like '%EAST%'
and upper(link) not like '%WEST%');
```

Comment: Thanks I have found many of those other links, there are thousands but the thing is that every campaign/offer combo must include one of the links N,S,E,W. The case expression is somehow missing some and then the query is finding them. So the ideal results for my second query would be for it to return no results. Then I would know that there is a campaign/offer out there that does not have one of the main links. I hope that makes sense.

Comment: The query I provided will list URLs that don't contain one of the main links... Isn't that what you're asking for?

Comment: Sorry I"m stupid...running your suggested query now.

Comment: Okay so I found a bunch of campain/offer combinations that came up. I then took some of those and ran them where                           upper(link)  like '%NORTH%'
or upper(link)  like '%SOUTH%'
or upper(link)  like '%EAST%'
or upper(link)  like '%WEST%'  and they all came back with results. So I checked and found that we have multiple combinations, for example, campaign A offer 2, was sent out twice. Once without the links that I'm looking for and a second or third time with the links that I'm searching for included.

Comment: So I talked to someone that thinks it could be a buffering issue and that is making the case statement miss some of them.

Comment: John, thanks for your help. I found a solution for it last night as I explained in my response to another comment on here and I will post my solution later today.

Answer (score 0):

So the table that I was running this for had tens of millions of rows and as mentioned in the comments above the case statement was bringing back Null due to many rows that yielded that result even if my link url was in there. I did not want to exclude all that resulted in NULL because there are some programs that truly should be null. I found that by bringing in all rows with their urls and grouping them, then selecting distinct values from that subset with my case statement included, then selecting again and running the case statement for all the remaining where division is still null did the trick. However, this did bring back duplicates so I had to use rownumber() to bring in everything I wanted. Basically to get rid of any NULL's where a true division already existed. There were some duplicates with different divisions but I needed to bring those in because that's another issue that has to be looked at. Here is my code and please feel free to let me know if there was an easier way to do this. Not sure if it matters but my table ran in about 5 minutes. Sorry if there are any typos, I had to recreate from my code to the fields and values here because our client is real big on privacy issues and although this would not put anything out there, it's just a headache I'd rather not deal with.

```
create table set_divisions as       
SELECT DISTINCT CAMPAIGNCODE, OFFERCODE, DIV        
FROM
(
    SELECT DISTINCT CAMPAIGN, OFFER, DIVISION
    ROWNUMBER() OVER
    (PARTITION BY CAMPAIGNCODE, OFFERCODE, ORDER BY DIVISION) AS RN
    FROM (SELECT DISTINCT CAMPAIGN, OFFER, DIVISION)
                case
                when upper(URL) like '%NORTH%'
                AND DIVISION IS NULL THEN 'NORTH'
                when upper(URL) like '%SOUTH%' 
                AND DIVISION IS NULL then 'SOUTH'
                when upper(URL) like '%EAST%'  
                AND DIVISION IS NULL then 'EAST'
                when upper(URL) like '%WEST%'  
                AND DIVISION IS NULL then 'WEST'
                ELSE DIVISION
                END AS DIV      
    FROM
    (
        SELECT DISTINCT CAMPAIGN, OFFER, DIVISION,
        CASE WHEN DIVISION IS NULL THEN LINK_URL
        ELSE NULL 
        END AS URL          
        FROM 
            (
                select campaign, offer, linkurl
                case
                when upper(link) like '%NORTH%' then 'NORTH'
                when upper(link) like '%SOUTH%' then 'SOUTH'
                when upper(link) like '%EAST%'  then 'EAST'
                when upper(link) like '%WEST%'  then 'WEST'
                ELSE NULL
                END AS DIVISION
                FROM TABLE A
                group by campaign, offer, linkurl
                case
                when upper(link) like '%NORTH%' then 'NORTH'
                when upper(link) like '%SOUTH%' then 'SOUTH'
                when upper(link) like '%EAST%'  then 'EAST'
                when upper(link) like '%WEST%'  then 'WEST'
            )               
    )                       
)   
    WHERE RN = 1
    OR (RN >1
        AND DIV IS NOT NULL);
```